# SwiftUI: Why doesn't ObservedObject work in AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit, combine

I've tried the example from the [ObservableObject documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject#3374830).

```swift
class Contact: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = "me"
    @Published var age: Int = 7
}
```

When I make a Swift Playground with the code:

```swift
let c = Contact()
c.objectWillChange.sink { print("This prints") }
c.age += 1
```

`objectWillChange` triggers and the line prints.

So far so good.

I now make a View in SwiftUI:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contact = Contact
    ...
```

I create this View in the AppDelegate, and do:

```swift
   contentView.contact.objectWillChange.sink { print("This doesn't print.") }
```

I've connected the contact to various controls, and changing any fields updates all the controls. Doing `onReceive(contact.objectWillChange)` also works fine. But not connecting to it in the AppDelegate. I've tried logging `deinit()` to make sure we're talking about the same object. I've tried using `ImmediateScheduler`. No dice. Why is this not working?

Comment: Why did you create a View in the appDelegate in the first place? 

Comment: On macOS, new project creates a `NSWindow` and sets the `contentView` to `NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())`

Comment: Just do it in `ContentView.swift`

Comment: Even doing it in `ContentView.swift` does not work, if I do it in the constructor or some such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a subscription with `.sink` you have to save the `AnyCancellable` object returned

```
let cancellable = publisher.sink { ... }
```

And if you assign it to a variable, make sure it is not short lived. As soon as the cancellable object gets deallocated, the subscription will get cancelled too.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! It even tried to warn me that I ignored the return value from `sink()`, but I was too cool for school...