# Swift ui macOS menuBar NSPopover no arrow

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, popover, nspopover

[image]

How do I remove the arrow from the NSPopover?

Can you give me a hand?

AppDelegate:

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var popover = NSPopover.init()
    var statusBar: StatusBarController?
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    @ObservedObject var userPreferences = UserPreferences.instance
        
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let contentView = ContentView()
        popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 560, height: 360)
        popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        statusBar = StatusBarController.init(popover)
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(interfaceModeChanged(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification"), object: nil)
        
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
    
    @objc func interfaceModeChanged(sender: NSNotification) {
        //popover.backgroundColor = colorScheme == .dark ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
        popover.backgroundColor = NSColor(named: "backgroundTheme")?.withAlphaComponent(userPreferences.backgroundIsTransparent ? 0.3 : 1.0)
        print("change")
    }
    
}
```

StatusBarController:

```swift
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

extension NSPopover {
    
    private struct Keys {
        static var backgroundViewKey = "backgroundKey"
    }
    
    private var backgroundView: NSView {
        let bgView = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &Keys.backgroundViewKey) as? NSView
        if let view = bgView {
            return view
        }
        
        let view = NSView()
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &Keys.backgroundViewKey, view, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(popoverWillOpen(_:)), name: NSPopover.willShowNotification, object: nil)
        return view
    }
    
    @objc private func popoverWillOpen(_ notification: Notification) {
        if backgroundView.superview == nil {
            if let contentView = contentViewController?.view, let frameView = contentView.superview {
                frameView.wantsLayer = true
                backgroundView.frame = NSInsetRect(frameView.frame, 1, 1)
                backgroundView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
                frameView.addSubview(backgroundView, positioned: .below, relativeTo: contentView)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var backgroundColor: NSColor? {
        get {
            if let bgColor = backgroundView.layer?.backgroundColor {
                return NSColor(cgColor: bgColor)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            backgroundView.wantsLayer = true
            backgroundView.layer?.backgroundColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
}

class StatusBarController {
    @ObservedObject var userPreferences = UserPreferences.instance
    private var popover: NSPopover
    private var statusBar: NSStatusBar
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem
    
    init(_ popover: NSPopover) {
        statusBar = NSStatusBar.init()
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        self.popover = popover
        self.popover.backgroundColor = NSColor(named: "backgroundTheme")?.withAlphaComponent(self.userPreferences.backgroundIsTransparent ? 0.3 : 1.0)
        
        if let statusBarButton = statusItem.button {
            statusBarButton.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Fork")
            statusBarButton.image?.size = NSSize(width: 18.0, height: 18.0)
            statusBarButton.image?.isTemplate = true
            statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(sender:))
            statusBarButton.target = self
            statusBarButton.imagePosition = NSControl.ImagePosition.imageLeft
        }
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(popover.isShown) {
            hidePopover(sender)
        } else {
            showPopover(sender)
        }
    }
    
    func showPopover(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let statusBarButton = statusItem.button {
            popover.show(relativeTo: statusBarButton.bounds, of: statusBarButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
        }
    }
    
    func hidePopover(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        popover.performClose(sender)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That is system NSPopover. You cannot remove the arrow. You can only code your own floating window. Again you posted your whole project -> voting to close as it needs more clarity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no public API for it I believe, try this instead:

```
popover.setValue(true, forKeyPath: "shouldHideAnchor")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I can ask you if by chance you had time to take a look at these two issues:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741461/swift-macos-popover-detect-change-dark-mode
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744074/swiftui-macos-appdelegate-detect-the-change-of-observedobject

Comment: Use of this might result to app store rejection as it's a private property. It is not meant for public use. (the answer already mentions this)

Comment: @MarekH Many devs use it, even in telegram you'll find private APIs getting called like this : https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/Telegram-iOS/blob/9131d607f7cf2c01c81ac492c25bed1b7e6f18f3/submodules/TelegramUI/Sources/AppDelegate.swift#L56-L57

Comment: @MarekH Don't you think this should get rejected too, for accessing private Ivar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29317022/6576315 , just curious.

Comment: @RTXGamer: Out of curiosity this is always a popover: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAhyv.png